# Slim 3 withRedirect problem and parameters

Tags: php, redirect, slim

I use Slim 3 and i want pass values to withRedirect

```
$app->get('/users/create/', function($request, $response, $args) use ($user){
    return $this->view->render($response, 'usuarios/crear.html', ['data'=> []]);
})->setName('root');
```

and I redirect

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('root', ['data'=> $input]));
```

and redirect but no show the new data. thx for read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of the `pathFor()` method is for routes with named placeholders like `/users/{id}`.

The 3. parameter of `pathFor($name, array $data = [], array $queryParams = [])` is for the query parameters.

**Example**

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('root', [], ['data'=> $input]));
```